# Return Axios data so I can use it

Tags: javascript

I am pulling some data from a local API I made for testing, and need to use the resulting data outside of the function. I am new to JS and am having trouble working with Promises.
Here is my code:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

function price_data () {
    return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/', {
      username: 'parke',
      password: 'password'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      var token = response['data']['access'];
      return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/price', {
      headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        var all_data = []
        for (i = 0; i < response['data'].length; i ++) {
          all_data.push(response['data'][i]['close'])
        }
        console.log(all_data);
        return(all_data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    })
}
console.log(price_data())
```

The result looks like this:

```
Promise { <pending> }
[
       1,      1,      1,      1,      1,      1,      1, 1.5907,
  1.5318, 1.5318, 1.5907, 1.5907, 1.5907, 1.5907, 1.5907, 1.5318,
  1.3551,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414, 1.3551, 1.2372, 1.2372,
   1.414,  1.414, 1.3551,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,
   1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414, 1.2961, 1.2961, 1.2961,
   1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414, 1.3551, 1.3551, 1.3551,
  1.3551, 1.3551, 1.3551, 1.3551, 1.3551, 1.2961, 1.2961, 1.2961,
  1.2961, 1.2961, 1.2961, 1.2961, 1.3551, 1.2961, 1.2961, 1.3551,
   1.414,  1.414,  1.414, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729,
  1.4729,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,  1.414,
   1.414,  1.414, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729, 1.4729,
  1.4729, 1.4729, 1.5907, 1.5613, 1.5907, 1.5465,  1.576, 1.5318,
  1.5318, 1.5539, 1.5907, 1.5907,
  ... 1101 more items
]
```

I kinda understand that the function is returning before the console.log prints, but I need to get that data that is being logged outside of the function. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me out real quick. Thanks!

Comment: Just do `price_data().then(data => { /* do whatever you want with it in here */})`. Or you may prefer to use `async/await`. The key is that axios, and therefore your function, returns a Promise.

Comment: read about async/await (promises) in JS because you need to understand them to understand your problem ;) to summary - this is not really axios issue

Comment: move your "all_data" variable up one level, immediately after the start of the block price_data func. Then return this value at the and of function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You should use .then,

```
console.log(price_data()) // This will return promise
price_data().then((data) => {
console.log(data); // This will contain the final return value from the promise axios.then.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with promises is that you cannot pull anything out of them, so every action with the response that you get by axios should be used with `.then()`

In your case it's `price_data().then(data => console.log(data))`

In the code above, you call `price_data()` function, which returns a promise with some data inside. After that you use `.then(data => console.log(data))` to console that data

I hope it helps,

Cheers

**EDIT**:
You can use async/await to assign data from promise to variable, but you will need to wrap your function into an async function like this:

```
async function getData (url) { // this is an async wrapping function
  function price_data () { // this is a function that you already have
    return axios(url)
  }
  const result = await price_data() // assign the data from price_data() to a varible using await 
  console.log(result) // console your variable
}
```

[Here you can learn more on async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

I really hope it will help you

Comment: Is there a way for me to set data to another variable so it can be used outside of any functions? My goal is really to just return the data, but when I return it even when I use price_data().then((data) => { it still gives me promise pending

Comment: Please, check my answer once again, I've edited it, so now it should answer your question

Comment: @ThomasParker asynchronous code is a big stumbling block for many, I suggest you read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) which approach this common problem from just about every conceivable angle.